# DBDelta: "table doesn't exist" for a table that was just created

Tags: wpdb, table, dbdelta

When I run the following code:

```
    global $wpdb;
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

    $table_tags = $wpdb->prefix . "tags_tb";
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_tags (
                tag text,
                tag_id tinyint,
                UNIQUE KEY id (id)
            ) $charset_collate"; 
    $array = dbDelta( $sql );
    print_r(array_values($array));

    echo $wpdb->insert( 
         $table_tags, 
         array( 
               'tag_id' => 1, 
               'tag' => "#AireLibre"
            ) 
         );  
    echo $wpdb->last_error;
```

I get the following output:

```
(
    [0] =&gt; Created table wp_tags_tb
)
Table 'acsm_28e28895e1cdaee.wp_tags_tb' doesn't exist
```

I think this doesn't make any sense. The table was created right but immediately when performing a query it doesn't exist.

Why can this happen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Glancing at your code I see a few potential problems.  According to this [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) dbDelta is "picky";

- You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
- You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of your primary key.
- You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.
- You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.
- Field types must be all lowercase.
- SQL keywords, like CREATE TABLE and UPDATE, must be uppercase.
- You must specify the length of all fields that accept a length parameter. int(11), for example.

The code you provided shows a unique key on a field that has not been created, there must be 2 spaces between KEY and the field name. There should be lengths specified where appropriate.

This [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/) page show where dbDelta is used by WP. Taking a look at those functions might help in dealing with dbDeltas "pickiness".

EDIT:

Here's an example from upgrade.php

```
function install_global_terms() {
    global $wpdb, $charset_collate;
    $ms_queries = "
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->sitecategories (
  cat_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  cat_name varchar(55) NOT NULL default '',
  category_nicename varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  last_updated timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (cat_ID),
  KEY category_nicename (category_nicename),
  KEY last_updated (last_updated)
) $charset_collate;
";
// now create tables
    dbDelta( $ms_queries );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think that is the problem because if not dbdelta would throw an error

Comment: Anyway, the problem was in that I was missing the line were I should have declare the key (id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT). I have no idea why this doesnt throw an error.